# Azure login from Salesforce Communities

Tags: integration, saml, login

I want to create a Web Tag in which I'm going to link a MS Azure app.
I want the customer to click the tag and automatically log in the Azure app without giving Azure the credentials.
I found many examples of just the opposite: How to log in to Salesforce from Azure setting Salesforce up as an Id Provider and using SAML protocol.

Is there any way I can to this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable MyDomain in SF and create a Connected App: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=connected_app_overview.htm

Azure side: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn641269.aspx